# Orbit Stabilizer problem (I think)

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ (finite) act transitively on the nonempty set $\Omega$. Show that if $\alpha \neq \beta$ are elements of $\Omega$ then $G_{\alpha}G_{\beta}$ is a proper subset of $G$, where $G_{\alpha}$ and $G_{\beta}$ are the stabilizers of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in G, respectively.

Here's what I've done:

Let $\mathcal{O}$ denote the orbit of the elements from $G$ acting on $\Omega$. Then using the orbit stabilizer theorem and the fact that $|G_{\alpha}G_{\beta}| = \frac{|G_{\alpha}||G_{\beta}|}{|G_{\alpha}\cap G_{\beta}|}$ we can deduce that
\begin{equation}
|G_{\alpha}G_{\beta}|=\frac{|G|^{2}}{|\mathcal{O}|^{2}\cdot |G_{\alpha} \cap G_{\beta}|}.
\end{equation}

**This is where I get stuck**. It is clear that $|G_{\alpha}|=|G_{\beta}|$ so I would like to argue that $G_{\alpha}=G_{\beta}$ so that $G_{\alpha} \cap G_{\beta} =G_{\alpha}=G_{\beta}$. This would then give that $G_{\alpha}G_{\beta}=\frac{|G|}{\mathcal{O}}$ since $|G_{\alpha}|=\frac{|G|}{\mathcal{O}}$ in which case I could probably make an argument for why $|\mathcal{O}| > 1$. It might not be true that the stabilizers for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are equal since I can't argue it in which case this would not work, obviously.

Comment: It might certainly be possible that $G_\alpha=G_\beta$, for instance if $G$ is cyclic. But it's not true in general. Rather, I think you should show that the subset $G_\alpha G_\beta$ is not transitive. Guess which element can't be sent to another specified element, then prove it.

Comment: Excellent idea I think ! I will give it a try (tomorrow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Size}[1]{\vert #1 \rvert}$I think you are nearly there with your approach.

Suppose $G = G_{\alpha} G_{\beta}$. Then
$$\Size{G} =
|G_{\alpha}G_{\beta}| 
= 
\frac{\Size{G_{\alpha}} \cdot \Size{G_{\beta}}}{\Size{G_{\alpha}\cap G_{\beta}}},$$
so that
$$
\Size{\Omega}
=
\frac{\Size{G}}{\Size{G_{\beta}}} = \frac{\Size{G_{\alpha}}}{\Size{G_{\alpha}\cap G_{\beta}}}.
$$
This is telling you that $G_{\alpha}$ is transitive on $\Omega$ (by orbit-stabilizer, as $G_{\alpha} \cap G_{\beta}$ is the stabilizer of $\beta$ in the action of $G_{\alpha}$ on $\Omega$), which is only possible of course when $\Omega = \{ \alpha \}$. But by assumption $\Omega$ contains at least two distinct elements $\alpha, \beta$.

---

**PS** I am assuming everything's finite here, since you were taking orders etc. But the result is true in general. It is equivalent to showing that a group cannot be the product of a proper subgroup $H$ and one of its conjugates $H^{g}$. ($G$ being transitive, all stabilizers are conjugate.) You can find a proof in [**this spoiler**](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Product_of_conjugates_is_proper) - $G$ is claimed to be finite there, but the proof works in general.

Comment: This seems correct. You did point out what should have been an obvious fallacy in my argument.. assuming the groups were finite when that was not an assumption. Nevertheless, it is enlightening to see the argument for finite case.

Comment: Thanks. I should add that @Andrew's comment points to an even slicker proof (which is equivalent to the one I linked to), that is, $G_{\alpha} G_{\beta}$ cannot take $\alpha$ to $\beta$.